# Can list become an element of set in python

Tags: python-2.7, set

I really wonder why the second one gives an error:
It would be really great if some one could pls highlight can we use lists as an element in set or it's not allowed to have any mutable object inside a set.
1)

```
>>> x = set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"])
>>> x
set(['Python', 'Java', 'Perl'])
>>>
```

2)

```
>>> cities = set((["Python","Perl"], ["Paris", "Berlin", "London"]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

Comment: Generally, you can't put mutable objects such as `list` or even anther `set` inside a set. If they are changed, that would affect whether they should be in the set at all. Technically, an object needs to be hashable to get in.

Comment: tdelany, we have lists in both (1) and (2) then why is it accepting in the 1st one and not in the 2nd one

Comment: `set()` accepts a sequence of hashable objects. A `list` is a sequence and since it only has hashable strings in it, the set is formed. When python displays the set, it uses list-notation to show the sequence, but its not 1 list item in the set, its all of the elements. Consider `set(xrange(3))` which will show up as `set([1,2,3]))` It wasn't a list going in, that's just how python shows the sequence.

Comment: tdelaney, that means if its only hashable strings inside the list then set can take list as an object...otherwise no?...is this the conclusion!!

Comment: No, the list doesn't become part of the set. The list is iterated and its iterated items become part of the set. After the set is constructed, it retains no memory of the original iterable object that produced the members. So, for instance `"Perl"` is a member of the set. `["Perl", "Python", "Java"]` is not a member of the set. Try `for item in set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"]):  print(item)` and you will see the strings printed.

Comment: thnx buddy, u cleared such a big doubt of mine.....I was under the assumption that list is passed to set builtin function which is stated on python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php....really thnx a ton!!!

Comment: `frozenset` is a different deal. Its job is to turn a mutable and unhashable `set` into an immutable and hashable object that can be in another set. Tuples are also hashable and if their members are hashable, they _can_ be used in a set. `set((("Python","Perl"), ("Paris", "Berlin", "London")))` works.

Comment: This confusion about sets was reduced in python 3 where the string representation uses a different notation. For instance, `set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"])` displays as `{'Java', 'Python', 'Perl'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you can't have a `list` as a member of a `set` (because it's not hashable).

I think you've been confused by the `repr` of the set in your first example. The output `set(['Python', 'Java', 'Perl'])` doesn't indicate that the set contains a 3-element list. Rather, it contains the three strings, with the list just being part of the notation the `repr` uses (since the set constructor expects an iterable of items). Note that the order of the items changes from your input to the the arbitrary order of the output!

In Python 3, the set type's `repr` uses set-literal syntax instead:

```
>>> x = set(["Perl", "Python", "Java"])
>>> x
{'Java', 'Perl', 'Python'}
```

Comment: Blckknght.......yeah exactly that confused me u noticed it perfectly right buddy, if we see on the below link we find they states that a list is passed tp set function which made me consider it as list.............

http://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php